# Using WS2007FederationHttpBinding with SOAP 1.1

Tags: wcf, wif

Is there a way to use WS2007FederationHttpBinding binding, but generate SOAP 1.1 request envelop? I need to use WS2007FederationHttpBinding to authenticate using a bearer token acquired from an STS service. Here is my bindings:

```
    private static Binding GetWS2007FederationHttpBinding()
    {
        var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(
            WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
        //binding.MessageVersion.Addressing = AddressingVersion.WSAddressingAugust2004;
        //binding.MessageVersion.Envelope = EnvelopeVersion.Soap11;
        // or
        //binding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004;
        return binding;
    }
```

But I can't change `binding.MessageVersion` because it's a read-only property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a custom binding for that. One way would be to statically declare a custom binding equivalent to WS2007FederationHttpBinding - could take a while to fine tune it. Or you could create WS2007FederationHttpBinding in code (like you do), clone it into a custom binding:

```
CustomBinding outputBinding = new CustomBinding(federationBinding.CreateBindingElements());
```

and then find the text message encoding channel and change its soap version.

Comment: Thanks this works. I didn't know one can create a custom binding from existing bindings, this opens a lot of possibilities.